# elmah customized provider and exposed event

Tags: c#, elmah

I am wondering how do I create my customized provider for storing the error logs, eg. a provider to windows event viewer.

If it is not possible so far, I am also wondering is there any exposed events I can override, so that I can inject my code, get the exception, do whatever I want.

I know there are some event I can override in Global.asax. like for filtering:

```
void ErrorLog_Filtering(object sender, ExceptionFilterEventArgs e)
{
}
void ErrorMail_Filtering(object sender, ExceptionFilterEventArgs )
{
}
```

is there more? where can I find the list of these events?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

About creating an Elmah Event Log provider it's probably not a good idea if you intend to store the error information in the event log and also use the ELMAH UI. A [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978555/log-errors-in-eventlog-using-elmah/2065146#2065146) has an excellent answer from Matthew Daugherty on this topic:

> ELMAH error log classes are not
>   write-only; they also read the log
>   data so that it can be displayed in
>   the ELMAH web interface. Additionally,
>   ELMAH logs more than just exception
>   information. It also logs server
>   variables, the form collection, and
>   the information necessary to reproduce
>   the yellow screen of death. Even if
>   you were to log all of this
>   information to the event log it would
>   be difficult to read as plain text,
>   and very difficult to read back in
>   such a way that the ELMAH web
>   interface could use it. If you are not
>   going to use the ELMAH web interface
>   then clearly that is not an issue.

In order to create a custom logging provider you can subclass ErrorLog and override the GetError (gets a single error by id; used by the Elmah UI), GetErrors (lists all errors on a page; used by the Elmah UI) and Log (logs a new error) methods to provide your own storage mechanism. See [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66610/Dynamically-setting-the-Elmah-connection-string-at.aspx) for an examle on how to implement a custom ErrorLog.

You then register your new ErrorLog provider in the config:

```
<elmah> 
  <errorLog type="MyNamespace.MyErrorLog, MyAssemblyName"/> 
</elmah>
```

Regarding the events, they are emitted by the Elmah modules. In the ErrorLogModule there are two events - Logged and Filtering. In the ErrorMailModule there are four events - Filtering, Mailing, Mailed and DisposingMail.

Comment: That pretty much answers my question, great!