# Is there an Elmah WriteLog event that I can hook into

Tags: elmah

For certain exceptions I want to append some information to my Elmah MVC log.

Is there a logging or pre-logging event that I can hook into to add this information to the log.

Currently all I can find is a ErrorLog_Logged event which is called after the log is created.

I guess I could use this event to grab the log id and then write a text file containing the extra information to my server but it would be easier if i can add this information to the actual Elmah log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that there are only ErrorLog_Logged and ErrorLog_Filtering events that are exposed by default with Elmah. In order to get the behavior that you are seeking, you can use the option you described in your question. Additionally, you could create a custom Elmah Event Log Provider that handles this for you. Here is a previous question - [Elmah Customized Provider and Exposed Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363088/elmah-customized-provider-and-exposed-event) that has some good details and links about how to do this.